# DI- Separation of Concerns Guidance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I Could do with some guidance on "separation of concerns". I am working on a Holiday booking application to try and better my DI and TDD knowledge,  I have two independent repositories "Allocation" and "PublicHoliday" they both have their own business logic class AllocationLogic and PublicHolidayLogic.

AllocationLogic has a method called CalculateWorkingDays, this method calculates which dates a user has to allocate holiday to, for a given range (the Start Date and End Date properties of the allocation object).

PublicHolidayLogic has a method called PublicHolidaysForTheYear which gets all the bank holidays for the year. rather than duplicating the code in this method to the CalculateWorkingDays method I want to call it from the PublicHolidayLogic class from within the CalculateworkingDays method.

My question is it OK to create an instance of the publicHolidayLogic class within the CalculateworkingDays method, pass in the required repositories via the Allocation constructor? or should i be passing in the Interface to publicholidaylogic in the allocation constructor.

I am hoping the former but i have attached my code, any help would be appreciated

-- Public Holiday Class

```
 public class PublicHolidayLogic : IPublicHolidayLogic
{
    private IPublicHolidayRepository _publicHolidayRepository;

    public PublicHolidayLogic(IPublicHolidayRepository publicHolidayRepo)
    {
        _publicHolidayRepository = publicHolidayRepo;
    }


    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Domain.Models.PublicHoliday> 
        PublicHolidaysForTheYear(int year, int countryId)
    {
        var returnedDates = _publicHolidayRepository.Enumerable()
            .Where(t => t.StartDate.Year == year && t.CountryId == countryId).ToList();

        List<Domain.Models.PublicHoliday> _result = new List<Domain.Models.PublicHoliday>();

        foreach(Domain.Models.PublicHoliday p in returnedDates)
        {
            if (!_result.Any(t => t.Name == p.Name && t.StartDate == p.StartDate))
              _result.Add(p);
        }

        return _result.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

-- Allocation Class

```
 public class AllocationLogic : IAllocationLogic
{
    private IAllocationRepository _allocationRepository;
    private IPublicHolidayRepository _publicHolidayRepository;

    public AllocationLogic(IAllocationRepository allocationRepo, 
                           IPublicHolidayRepository publicHolidayRepository)
    {
        _allocationRepository = allocationRepo;
        _publicHolidayRepository = publicHolidayRepository;
    }

    public int CalculateWorkingDays(Domain.Models.Allocation allocation)
    {
        //TODO A Better way of doing this would be nice.
        List<DateTime> _dates = new List<DateTime>();
        List<DateTime> _result = new List<DateTime>();

        //Monday To Friday Only

        for (DateTime i = allocation.StartDate; i <= allocation.EndDate; i = i.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (i.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday 
                && i.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday 
                && !_dates.Contains(i))

                _dates.Add(i);
        }

        //Remove Bank Holidays
        if (_publicHolidayRepository != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Domain.Models.PublicHoliday> _holidays 
                = new PublicHolidayLogic(_publicHolidayRepository)
                    .PublicHolidaysForTheYear(allocation.StartDate.Year, allocation.User.CountryId);

            if (_holidays.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (DateTime d in _dates)
                {
                    if (!_holidays.Any(t => t.StartDate == d))
                    {
                        _result.Add(d);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _result.AddRange(_dates);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _result.AddRange(_dates);
        }
        return _result.Count;

    }
}
```

-- Allocation Test Class

```
[TestClass]
public class AllocationLogicTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void CalculateWorkingDaysOnly()
    {
        //Holiday
        var allocation = new Allocation { 
            StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 7), 
            EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 18) 
        };
        var user = new User { CountryId = 1 };

        var allocationLogic = new AllocationLogic(null,null);

        allocation.User = user;
        int result = allocationLogic.CalculateWorkingDays(allocation);

        Assert.AreEqual(10, result);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CalculateWorkingDaysWithBankHoliday()
    {

        //Holiday
        var allocation = new Allocation { 
            StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 7), 
            EndDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 18) 
        };
        var publicHoliday = new List<PublicHoliday> { 
            new PublicHoliday { CountryId = 1, StartDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 10), 
            Name = "My Bank Holiday" } 
        };
        var user = new User { CountryId = 1 };

        var mock = new Mock<IPublicHolidayRepository>();
        mock.Setup(s => s.Enumerable()).Returns(publicHoliday.AsEnumerable());


        allocation.User = user;

        var allocationLogic = new AllocationLogic(null,mock.Object);

        int result = allocationLogic.CalculateWorkingDays(allocation);

        Assert.AreEqual(9, result);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing separation of concerns with coupling. You are tightly coupling PublicHolidayLogic to AllocationLogic though creating an instance of one within the other.

In reality, all AllocationLogic needs is access to the method. Change AllocationLogic's constructor to have an extra parameter of type `Func<int, int, IEnumerable<PublicHoliday>>` and store it in a private field with the same type, eg called `_publicHolidayFunc`. Then in the code that creates the two classes, do this:

```
var publicHoliday = new PublicHolidayLogic(publicHolidayRepo);
var allocationLogic = new AllocationLogic(allocationRepo, 
                                          publicHolidayRepo, 
                                          publicHoliday.PublicHolidaysForTheYear);
...
```

Finally change the method to:

```
if (_publicHolidayRepository != null)
{
    var holidays = _publicHolidayFunc(allocation.StartDate.Year, allocation.User.CountryId);

    if (_holidays.Count() > 0)
    {
        ...
```

You are then using DI to inject the required method, decoupling the two classes from each other.

Comment: I don't like the approach where you couple to `Func<something, somethingelse, yetanotherone>`. This would be difficult to maintain as it suddenly introduces the method-level contract in a world of class-level contracts. On the other hand, I don't see anyhting wrong in "layering" your services, where the `PublicHolidayLogic` is a part of the lower layer and can be injected into `AllocationLogic`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I fail to see how this causes maintenance problems. Quite the opposite is true. The contract is reduced from an entire class to just one function. The aim should be to move away from class-level contracts as it couples functionality and potentially hinders separation of concerns. It's worth bearing in mind that one of the reasons for the growing popularity of functional languages is because it encourages these fined grained contracts.

Comment: One of the reasons this doesn't work well is that DI containers make you think at the class/interface level contract. How would you register a global dependency to `Func<something, somethingelse, yetanotherone>` when it could have **different** meanings in different contexts? On the other hand, two interfaces `IA` and `IB` could even have the same contract but still are two different interfaces. `

Comment: @WiktorZychla So what you are saying is that one of the reasons why some DI containers don't work too well is because they cannot cope with fine-grained, function-level, injections. Seems a good reason to avoid those DI containers to me.

Comment: Can you give an example of an actual container where your method-level contract could be registered and resolved and when another contract of the same signature is used in a different context, you still can register/resolve and you still can maintain it? I am not biased, I would love to learn something useful, however, I can't see a clean way of doing it.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Much to my surprise it looks like I have to change "some DI containers" to "all DI containers". Guess that explains why I'm still rolling my own DI. I feel an SO question coming on in order to confirm this though. :)

Comment: That's what I thought ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response, it has been most helpful. Sorry about the confusion between separation of concerns and coupling

Answer (score 1):

> My question is it OK to create an instance of the publicHolidayLogic class within the CalculateworkingDays method, pass in the required repositories via the Allocation constructor? or should i be passing in the Interface to publicholidaylogic in the allocation constructor.

The latter. You don't want to couple an implementation to another implementation. In your world you you couple to contracts, keep doing it then.

It is quite possible that instead of passing repositories around

```
public AllocationLogic( IAllocationRepository allocationRepo, 
                        IPublicHolidayRepository publicHolidayRepository )
...
```

you'll end up with passing services

```
public AllocationLogic( IPublicHolidayLogic publicHolidayService )
...
```

Comment: do know how to amend my unit test to reflect this change, i believe, I still need to mock the IPublicHolidayLogic but  it still takes a IPublicHolidayRepository?

Comment: From what I can see, you are not using the `IPublicHolidayRepository` in `AllocationLogic` to anything else than to create the `PublicHolidayLogic`. If the `AllocationLogic` has the `IPublicHolidayLogic` injected instead, then your unit test changes accordingly, you mock the `IPublicHolidayLogic`.